# Calling function from Oracle PL/SQL bad bind

Tags: sql, oracle, bind

I've been stuck at this for hours and not sure why. 
There's a function create_blob_thumbnail() that passes in images.image_id, to create a thumbnail of the blob image in the images table.

If I run in SQL developer `create_blob_thumbnail(1);` then that works fine, as I'm passing in an image id.

I'd like to create a trigger after insert of the images table to run that function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_thumbs
AFTER INSERT 
  ON images
  REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  create_blob_thumbnail(:new.IMAGE_ID);
END;
```

But I get the `Bad bind variable 'IMAGE_ID` error. I've tried it without the `:new.` but it tells me that it must be declared.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does the column IMAGE_ID exist in images table?

Comment: It does. I can run `select image_id from images` and it'll output the image IDs

Comment: Why is there a single-quote in front of `'IMAGE_ID`?

Comment: Try it as `create_blob_thumbnail(:new."image_id");`.

Comment: Tiredness, missed off the second quote. And it just compiles, not created. Has a pop-up for a binding.

Comment: `bad bind variable 'NEW.image_id`

Comment: I think your IDE thinks of :xxx as of bind variables. There is nothing wrong with the trigger. Turn off bindings in your editor

Comment: I had to log into APEX to see if it was the same. I removed the quotes and it worked. But now stops any new rows being inserted into the table

Comment: I found the problem I was having. The trigger locked the table preventing new rows being being created. The function should have gone into the procedure to upload the image, and create the thumbnail before the commit